# WSO2 ESB -How to set HTTPS port for proxy services other than management console HTTPS port

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am using ESB 4.0.3 on Mac OSX 10.7.5.

Java version is

java version "1.6.0_35" /
   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_35-b10-428-11M3811) / 
   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.10-b01-428, mixed mode)

In my axis2.xml I am using have following configuration for HTTPS transport listner

```
 <transportReceiver name="https" class="org.wso2.carbon.core.transports.http.HttpsTransportListener">
    <parameter name="port" locked="true">9443</parameter>
</transportReceiver>
```

In my mgt-transports.xml I have following configuration

```
     <parameter name="port" locked="xsd:false">${Ports.ServletTransports.HTTPS}</parameter>
```

In my carbon.xml I have following configuration

```
      <ServletTransports>
        <HTTPS>9440</HTTPS>
        <HTTP>9763</HTTP>
    </ServletTransports>
```

How ever when I start the ESB the proxy / Data services on HTTPS port never listen to 9443 where as they listen on 9440 all the time.

How can I enable HTTPS port for the proxy and Data services  different than the management console HTTPS port?

Please let me know.
thanks
Abhijit

Hi Nuwan

I am not using NHTTP transport. Please see the transportlistener class above. I am using servelet transport only for the ESB as my requirement is not to disturb existing HTTP client.

For servlet transport in ESB I would like to know if ADMIN UI port can be different than the ESB proxy services HTTPS port.

Please help. 
Abhijit

Answer (score 0):

Are mentioning about ESB proxy services ?, If so they do not listen to the servlet transport. They are working on NHHTP transport which you can configure. Please provide more information. whats the NHTTP ports in ESB ?

Regards,
/Nuwan

Comment: Hi Nuwan I have updated the question. Please see the transport listener snippet from axis2.xml. I am not using NHTTP but servlet transport. Please help with the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the servlet transport for ESB, the same port will be used by Admin Console UI. You cannot do anything for that, since there is only one Servlet transport Admin UI will also use that.

Regards,
/Nuwan